# Auto Select one item on Dropdownlist asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have dropdownlist with list item of Yes and No. I want "No" will be displayed on the page but the Selected="true" on the ListItem is not working.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIsDistributor" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem  Value="1" Text="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem  Value="0" Text="No" Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>

                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I belive you should try to use `true` small caps ... else you can also add a code behind like `ddlIsDistributor.SelectedValue = 1`

Comment: looking at the [declarative syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist?view=netframework-4.8#DeclarativeSyntax) for `asp:DropDownList`, `Selected="True"` should work on a `asp:ListItem`. I can't even reproduce your issue.

Comment: I resolved the issue now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Invoke this bit of code in your page load event so it selects the desired value from the dropdown when loading: `ddlIsDistributor.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: Your question should have an answer, accept one, provide a solution or delete it :)